# SQL Server query stuck when adding order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by, inner-join

I'm working on writing some queries for a very large (and messy) database on behalf of a client. So far, I've just been grabbing the columns I need and making sure that they contain the data I'm looking for. There have been no issues up until I add anything to my "order by" clause. When I add an order by clause to my query, the SQL Server remains stuck on "executing query." Example of code below:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
   PEATR.[EffectiveDate] AS 'Effective Date', 
   CustomerRoot.[CustomerName] AS 'Name',  
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street1] AS 'Address 1', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street2] AS 'Address 2', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[City],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[State], 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Zip],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Country],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[AddressDesc] AS 'Description' 
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR, CustomerRoot, CustomerAddressRoot
ORDER BY CustomerRoot.[CustomerName]
```

I have also tried creating an inner join on CustomerRoot and CustomerAddressRoot, as the query is returning repeat data, especially in the "Address 1" column. When I ran the code below, I have received the following error message:

> The objects "CustomerRoot" and "CustomerRoot" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
   PEATR.[EffectiveDate] AS 'Effective Date', 
   CustomerRoot.[CustomerName] AS 'Name',  
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street1] AS 'Address 1', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street2] AS 'Address 2', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[City],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[State], 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Zip],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Country],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[AddressDesc] AS 'Description'
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR, CustomerRoot, CustomerAddressRoot
INNER JOIN CustomerRoot ON CustomerAddressRoot.CustomerId=CustomerRoot.CustomerId
```

I did assign aliases to all of the tables previously, though I was still returning the same error message. Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: *Presumably* you don't have an index on `CustomerRoot.[CustomerName]` and due to the dataset being large (before the `TOP`), due to the `CROSS JOIN`s on your 3 tables, the instance needs to sort the entire lot with a table scan. Do you *really* want a Cartesian productof the tables `PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot`, `CustomerRoot` and `CustomerAddressRoot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a cartesian join.

```
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR, CustomerRoot, CustomerAddressRoot
```

...is the same as...

```
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR
  inner join CustomerRoot on 1=1
  inner join CustomerAddressRoot on 1=1
```

There is no join logic.

So, if `PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot` has 1000 rows and `CustomerRoot` has 1000 rows and `CustomerAddressRoot` has 1000 rows, your result will have 1,000,000,000 rows.

Try two things:

1. Include join logic.

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
   PEATR.[EffectiveDate] AS 'Effective Date', 
   CustomerRoot.[CustomerName] AS 'Name',  
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street1] AS 'Address 1', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street2] AS 'Address 2', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[City],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[State], 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Zip],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Country],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[AddressDesc] AS 'Description' 
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR
  inner join CustomerRoot on CustomerRoot.customerrootid = peatr.customerrootid
  inner join CustomerAddressRoot on CustomerAddressRoot.customerrootid = CustomerRoot.customerrootid
ORDER BY CustomerRoot.[CustomerName]
```

Of course, I don't know what columns you should actually join on.  Know thy data.

Then you'll have one problem remaining:  If your query (without the `TOP 100`) would return millions of rows, you're asking the database server to perform all of the logic and gather all of the rows, then sort them by `CustomerName`, then return the first 100 rows.  That could still be slow.  You'll want to...

2. Apply filters.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
   PEATR.[EffectiveDate] AS 'Effective Date', 
   CustomerRoot.[CustomerName] AS 'Name',  
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street1] AS 'Address 1', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Street2] AS 'Address 2', 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[City],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[State], 
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Zip],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[Country],
   CustomerAddressRoot.[AddressDesc] AS 'Description' 
FROM PrEmployeeAccrueTierRoot AS PEATR
  inner join CustomerRoot on CustomerRoot.customerrootid = peatr.customerrootid
  inner join CustomerAddressRoot on CustomerAddressRoot.customerrootid = CustomerRoot.customerrootid
WHERE CustomerAddressRoot.State = 'Alaska'
ORDER BY CustomerRoot.[CustomerName]
```

..at least during testing, to speed things up.

Comment: This was incredibly useful advice. Query is now running perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!